# Issue inserting node in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am practicing creating a link list, but encountered a problem when trying to insert an item to the front of the list. The code in my insert function works properly if I put it within main, but not when run separately as a function.

I am using a pointer as a argument in the function so I don't understand why the value in my print statement isn't changing to 100 which should be at the front of the linked list using the insert function (When I run the function 61 is printed, I am aiming for 100 to be printed).

Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *nodePtr;
typedef struct node node;

struct node {
    int value;
    nodePtr next;
};


node insert(node *first, int value)
{
    nodePtr temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->value = value;
    temp->next = first;
    first = temp;
}

int main()
{

    nodePtr first;
    first = malloc(sizeof(node));
    first->value = 61;
    first->next = NULL;
    insert(first, 100);

    printf("%d", first->value);
}
```

Comment: question makes zero sense. your code clearly shows that 61 will be printed.

Comment: Assign with `61` but expect `100` output, how could do this?

Comment: My mistake, I accidentally deleted the insert(first, 100) line that should be below first->next = NULL; when editing the code. I will change it in the main post as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your passing a pointer to the node as a argument to the function and changing the value of formal parameter does not change the value of the actual parameter do this it should work.

```
enter code here



#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

   typedef struct node *nodePtr;
   typedef struct node node;

  struct node {
  int value;
  nodePtr next;
   };


 void insert(node **first, int value)
 {
 nodePtr temp;
 temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
 temp->value = value;
 temp->next = *first;
 *first = temp;
  }

 int main()
 {

nodePtr first;
first = malloc(sizeof(node));
first->value = 61;
first->next = NULL;
insert(&first, 100);
printf("%d",first->value);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out, and it seems like the value that is stored ends up being some random long number. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: I found my error, I was passing in first rather than &first in my insert function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have passed a pointer to function *insert()* and stored it in a variable *first* whose scope is local to function *insert()*. Now you have
updated pointer *first* in function *insert()*.

When you will return to *main()* function updated value of pointer *next* is lost that is why you are getting unexpected result while printing value in main().

To summarise:

```
first = malloc(sizeof(node)); // let's say first is p1
...
insert(first, 100); // first is P1
....

node insert(node *first, int value) // first is p1
....
tmp = malloc(sizeof(node)); // let's say tmp is p2
first = temp; // Now first has become p2 but its scope is local to insert()

....
printf("%d", first->value); // first is still p1 here
```

**Solution**

```
node* insert(node *first, int value)
{
    nodePtr temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->value = value;
    temp->next = first;
    first = temp;
    return first;
}

int main()
{

    nodePtr first;
    first = malloc(sizeof(node));
    first->value = 61;
    first->next = NULL;
    first = insert(first, 100);

    printf("%d", first->value);
    return 0;
}
```